# Adding dates to the database that can be used to specify an active week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the process of creating an competition app that needs to be pretty much autonomous. The app has a resource called 'Weeks' and each week has many 'Entries'. Users can add an entry to the week, and then they can be voted on.

The week has a database column called 'start_date' and if I populate this with a string, eg "16-03-2015" then on the Show view I can pull in the weeks params and compare the string to todays date and set whether the vote buttons are active or not.

In my weeks controller I use a before action called set_dates and I set a couple of variables

```
def set_dates
    @today = Date.today
    @weekstart = Date.parse(@week.active_date)
    @weekend = Date.parse(@week.active_date)+7
end
```

I can then set if and else statements on the view to show the vote buttons if the week is 'active', ie. todays date is within the active_date + 7 days

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
    <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(entry.photo(:thumb)) %>
        <%= entry.cached_votes_up %>

        <% if (@weekstart..@weekend).include? @today %>
            <%= link_to "Upvote", upvote_week_entry_path(entry.week_id, entry) %>
            <%= link_to "Downvote", downvote_week_entry_path(entry.week_id, entry) %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This was fine until I realised I needed to have an 'active week' outside of the show view. I want to put a link into the Navigation Bar in the application_layout to 'This Weeks Comp', and I need this week to point to whichever week voting is active on. But without finding the week by its ID, then cross referencing it's active_date, I am unsure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this: Do you need really need the `Week` resource? Why not just have `Entry` with `start`, `end` and a boolean field (`active`) that gets updated with a cronjob and iterate through the active ones or those that fall in a specific daterange?

Comment: Hey Sebkomianos, thanks for the suggestion, the entire concept of the competition revolves around weeks, and once they're over the results should remain viewable, so it made more sense to have a weeks resource. I eventually managed to scope the active weeks in the application controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is find this looking to solve a similar problem, I solved the issue by adding an end_date  column to the weeks resource, and then assigned a variable to an arel query in the application controller

App-Controller

```
  before_action :active_week

  protected

  def active_week
    @aweek = Week.where("? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date", Date.today)
    @active = @aweek.first
  end
```

Application Layout

```
 <%= link_to "This Week", @active %>
```